# Div Floats in Other Div

Tags: css, html, css-float

Html

```
<div id="middle" style="width="600px">
        <div id="section1" class="section"></div>
        <div id="section2" class="section"></div>
        <div id="section3" class="section"></div>   

</div>
```

I need divs float left in middle div.So i want to make a slide div

[Css here](http://udesgn.net/css.txt)

Comment: do you want them to be in horizontal sequence ?

Comment: yes horizontal sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display:inline-block` (*and remove the float*) on the `.section` elements, and make the container `.middle` to be `white-space:nowrap`

```
<div id="middle" style="width:600px">
        <div id="section1" class="section"></div><div id="section2" class="section"></div><div id="section3" class="section"></div>   
</div>

#middle{
    display:block;
    width:639px;
    height:600px;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    }
.section{
    width:639px;
    height:600px;
    background:#333;
    display:inline-block;
    }
```

(*notice that i have remove the whitespace between each `.section` element to avoid a space between them..*)

Comment: i have little problem on this code everything ok but there is 1 px space near all divs :S

Comment: Did you follow the notice I put in the end.. you need to remove whitespace between the div elements.. if you did and the problem is still there, please post a link so we can see it live..

Answer (score 0):

Try this (bunu dene):

```
<div id="middle" style="width="600px">
    <div align="left" id="section1" class="section"></div>
    <div align="left" id="section2" class="section"></div>
    <div align="left" id="section3" class="section"></div>   
</div>
```